# Exchange data b/w iOS devices using Bluetooth 4.0

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, gamekit, core-bluetooth

I am looking into how to exchange data (information/files/etc.) between multiple iOS devices using Bluetooth 4.0. What frameworks are better to use to do that? Will Core Bluetooth do the work, or GameKit?

Any help, tips, recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CoreBluetooth framework will work for information/file exchange on iOS 6+ devices with Bluetooth 4.0 (iPhone 4s and 5, iPod Touch Gen 5, iPad Gen 3 and 4, iPad Mini). It has a range of about 50 meters and a data rate of about ~2 KB per second.

I would recommend checking out the app [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) if you want to play around with connecting 2 iOS 6 devices together. It will let you read and write between the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Core Bluetooth will work, but only under iOS 6. Core Bluetooth under iOS 5 only allows the iOS device to function as a master (a device that detects broadcasting BLE devices and connects to them), not as a slave (a device that broadcasts its existence and connects to master devices who want its services).

There are some good overviews of the differences and technologies in the videos from WWDC 2012. Look for:

Session 703 - Core Bluetooth 101

Session 705 - Advanced Core Bluetooth

in the video sessions from WWDC, which can be found in the developer section of Apple's web site.