# Working with bluetooth in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, gamekit, multipeer-connectivity

I was trying to make a connection between two devices initially using bluetooth ( To send messages and files ) , the first framework I found to do this kind of thing was the GameKit but unfortunately it was discontinued and I was forced to use the MultipeerConnectivity framework.

Recently I learned of the Core-Bluetooth framework that can communicate with other peripherals , performing an internet search I realized that most of the tutorials related to it, are temperature peripherals and heart monitor. Unfortunately I do not know if it is possible to connect two devices with this framework and hold an exchange of information ( messages and files ) the same way you do with MultipeerConnectivity framework, it is possible?

In this case there are only these three frameworks that can connect via bluetooth or are there others?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exchange data b/w iOS devices using Bluetooth 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488274/exchange-data-b-w-ios-devices-using-bluetooth-4-0)

Answer (score 3):

Core Bluetooth is all that you need to connect two devices. There is no need for third-party frameworks. Even though most tutorials and examples are related to temperature and heart monitors, they demonstrate the basic concepts of connecting to peripherals and transferring data between the two. Also, if you are using a third party Bluetooth or BLE chip, reference the API that came along with it.

This tutorial should be enough to get you going. It demonstrates basic broadcasting, connecting the transferring data:

[Practical Core Bluetooth Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741)

And if you want to learn about the more inner-workings of Core Bluetooth, check out Apple's Docs:
[About Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hey @John I try this tutorial and get this code: https://github.com/orepereira/CoreBluetooth

Comment: I have two devices to test this project (iphone 4s and ipad 3) all of them have bluetooth turned ON, I run this project in theses devices, and in iphone4s I put to central, and ipad put to Peripheral, In console I see that iphone4s start scanning but not find any devices... why?

Comment: Note that iphone4s have iOS 8.0, and ipad 3 have iOS 8.1.1

Comment: @BelzumNulls Have you tried the tutorial I posted above?

Comment: Yes, but not change in my app

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [LGBluetooth](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth).  It is a lightweight library for interacting with CoreBluetooth.  It lets you send serial data to connected devices and peripherals.